# Why does apply_instance fail to generate decidable_pred here?

Tags: lean

Here is a stripped down version of something that is causing me trouble.

```
variables {α : Type*} [decidable_eq α]

def S (a : α) : set α := λ b, b = a

def P (a : α) : decidable_pred (λ (c : α), c = a) := 
 by { apply_instance, }

def Q (a : α) : decidable_pred (λ (c : α), c ∈ (S a)) := 
 by { simp[S], apply_instance, }
```

Lean is happy with the definition of `P`, but rejects the definition of `Q` as follows:

```
tactic.mk_instance failed to generate instance for
  decidable_pred (λ (c : α), c ∈ λ (b : α), b = a)
state:
α : Type u_1,
_inst_1 : decidable_eq α,
a : α
```

In both `P` and `Q`, we ask `tactic.mk_instance` to generate a decision procedure for a predicate.  The predicate in `Q` is equivalent under β-reduction to the one in `P`, but `tactic.mk_instance` succeeds with `P` but fails with `Q`.  Is this just a weakness in the tactic or is there some more subtle issue?  Is there some straightforward way to work around this kind of problem?

Comment: Great question!

Comment: The bounty was always 100 points.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The predicate in Q is equivalent under β-reduction to the one in P

Not according to Lean in this case. `set.mem` is a `def`, which are not unfolded during typeclass inference by default. Thus inference fails at unifying it with `=`:

```
set_option trace.type_context.is_def_eq_detail true
```

```
[class_instances]  class-instance resolution trace
[class_instances] (0) ?x_0 a_1 : decidable ((λ (c : α), c ∈ λ (b : α), b = a) a_1) := _inst_1 (?x_1 a_1) (?x_2 a_1)
[type_context.is_def_eq_detail] [1]: decidable ((λ (c : α), c ∈ λ (b : α), b = a) a_1) =?= decidable (?x_1 a_1 = ?x_2 a_1)
[type_context.is_def_eq_detail] [2]: (λ (c : α), c ∈ λ (b : α), b = a) a_1 =?= ?x_1 a_1 = ?x_2 a_1
[type_context.is_def_eq_detail] after whnf_core: a ∈ λ (b : α), b = a_1 =?= ?x_1 a = ?x_2 a
[type_context.is_def_eq_detail] [3]: @set.mem α a (λ (b : α), b = a_1) =?= ?x_1 a = ?x_2 a
[type_context.is_def_eq_detail] [4]: set.mem =?= eq
[type_context.is_def_eq_detail] on failure: set.mem =?= eq
[type_context.is_def_eq_detail] on failure: @set.mem α a (λ (b : α), b = a_1) =?= ?x_1 a = ?x_2 a
[type_context.is_def_eq_detail] on failure: decidable ((λ (c : α), c ∈ λ (b : α), b = a) a_1) =?= decidable (?x_1 a_1 = ?x_2 a_1)
failed is_def_eq
```

We can fix this with either `local attribute [reducible] set.mem` or `simp[S, set.mem]`.

This still begs the question, why is `set.mem` (and others, including `set` itself) not marked as reducible? AFAIR this was a conscious decision to prevent it from "unexpectedly" unfolding and thus mixing the "world of sets" with the "world of predicates". People usually think of them as separate concepts, so it can be confusing when your goals are suddenly switched to the other world.

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to fix my original problem by reformulating it with predicates rather than sets, although mathematically that seemed less idiomatic in the relevant context.  Perhaps `simp[S,set.mem]` would have been better.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure about the exact meaning of the question. But indeed `apply_instance` is simply not trying to do β-reduction before working.

```
variables {α : Type*} [decidable_eq α]

def S (a : α) : set α := λ b, b = a

def P (a : α) : decidable_pred (λ (c : α), c = a) := 
 by { apply_instance, }

def Q (a : α) : decidable_pred (λ (c : α), c ∈ (S a)) := 
show decidable_pred (λ (c : α), c = a),  by apply_instance
```

certainly works.

Comment: weird that `simp` refuses to do the beta-reduction, though!

Comment: Now you can comment everywhere. :)